# How can I display item on QListWidget when it match with the search term

Tags: python, pyqt5

I try to make a function that display item (from the list "data" below) on QlistWidget when the search term is contained in the item.

The function is below:

```
self.data = ["France","France","Allemagne","Serbie","Ile Maurice","States"]
self.qle = QLineEdit(self) 
self.listwidget = QListWidget()

def update_display(self):
    
    out = self.data.filter(self.qle.text(),Qt.MatchContains)
    
    self.listwidget.addItems(out)
```

But it show me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "InterfaceGraphique.py", line 53, in update_display
out = self.data.filter(self.qle.text(),Qt.MatchContains)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter
```

I exactly know what is the problem but I can't try to find the solution for replace it.

Comment: `out = [item for item in self.data if self.qle.text() in item]`

Comment: @Heike It works thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare strings against patterns, give a try to the regular expressions module

```
import re

self.data = ["France","France","Allemagne","Serbie","Ile Maurice","States"]
self.qle = QLineEdit(self) 
self.listwidget = QListWidget()

def update_display(self):

    for item in item in data:
        if re.search(self.qle.text(),item):    
            self.listwidget.addItems(item)
            break
```

re.search matches the pattern anywhere in the target string. If you wish to match on the beggining of the string, use re.match. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html